# Use tags with the @benchmarkset macro in Julia BenchmarkTools

Tags: julia

Is there a way to use tags with the `@benchmarkset` macro? I’ve been searching the documentation but to no avail.

Comment: I don't think there is. Tbh I'd avoid that macro all together since there's a bug right now https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl/issues/221